# Constant space and linear time balanced parenthesis algorithm exists?

Tags: algorithm

I know that we can check if the parenthesis are balanced in the string by using a stack in linear time. But I was asked in an interview that I have to do this in linear or lesser time using constant space. I can not think of way to accomplish this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: just increment on finding opening parenthesis and decrement on closing one. and "lesser than linear time" doesn't make sense

Comment: Well, when you say parentheses, does it have only `(` and `)` or can it also have `[`,`]`,`{`,`}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many opening parentheses minus how many closing parentheses have been seen so far. If it ever goes below zero, you have a closing parenthesis that doesn't match an opening parenthesis before it. If it's not zero at the end, you have an unmatched opening parenthesis.